# proFTPD with FTPS (openssl)

Tags: linux, ftp, openssl, ftps, proftpd

Have installed `proFTPD` from webmin and it works...

Then I would like to support FTPS

## command line

```
apt-get install openssl
mkdir /etc/proftpd/ssl
cd /etc/proftpd/ssl
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 9999 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout private.key -out public.crt
```

## /etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf

```
<IfModule mod_tls.c>
TLSEngine                  on
TLSLog                     /var/log/proftpd/tls.log
TLSProtocol                SSLv23
TLSOptions                 NoCertRequest
TLSRSACertificateFile      /etc/proftpd/ssl/public.crt
TLSRSACertificateKeyFile   /etc/proftpd/ssl/private.key
TLSVerifyClient            off
TLSRequired                on
</IfModule>
```

## nmap localhost

```
Starting Nmap 6.46 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-08-03 22:50 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000010s latency).
Not shown: 995 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
21/tcp    open  ftp
22/tcp    open  ssh
80/tcp    open  http
3306/tcp  open  mysql
10000/tcp open  snet-sensor-mgmt
```

## Log FileZilla (client)

```
Status: Connecting to domain.com...
Response:   fzSftp started
Command:    open "user@domain.com" 22
Command:    Pass: ******
Status: Connected to domain.com
Error:  Connection closed by server with exitcode 1
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Response:   fzSftp started
 Command:    open "user@domain.com" 22
```

Port 22 is ssh. Which means you are trying to use sftp (file transfer over ssh) and not ftps (ftp with ssl). But with proftpd you have to use either ftp or ftps.

Comment: ok.. have updated my qustion with `nmap localhost`.. only port 21 is open.. which port is `ftps` using?

Comment: @clarkk: There are various kinds of FTPS. There is ftps on port 990 with SSL from start (similar to imaps or https). But this was never standardized. FTP with TLS instead is standardized in RFC4217 and provides an TLS upgrade inside a plain connection, similar to STARTTLS in imap or smtp. In this case it continues to use port 21 (ftp).